# Borel sigma algebras of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, borel-sets

I'm trying to prove a result that seems to be used routinely, but the proof is skipped over.

Let $\mathbb{R}$ have the Euclidean metric, and this defines a topology. Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be equipped with the subspace topology. Then,

1. $\mathcal{B}(A) = \{ B \cap A : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$
2. If $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, then $\mathcal{B}(A) = \{ B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) : B \subset A\}$.

The proof for the $\subset$ direction of 1. is simple; note that $\{ B \cap A : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$ is a sigma algebra, which contains all the open sets of $A$. There are also other questions on stackexchange which address this direction of the proof. However, I am stuck on the $\supset$ direction. Does anyone have a nice proof for this?

(2. is an immediate consequence of 1., as far as I can see)

Comment: By definition of the subspace topology, the open subsets of $A$ are the sets $A \cap B$ where $B$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: As per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set#Generating_the_Borel_algebra , I can imagine one could use transfinite induction on ordinals up to $\omega_1$ to prove $\mathcal B(A)\supseteq\{B\cup A:B\in G^\alpha(\mathbb R)\}$ for all ordinals $\alpha<\omega_1$, from which the claim should immediately follow ... however (a) I am not an expert so take this only as a hint; (b) I would like to see a more elementary proof too.

Comment: @StinkingBishop yes, I'm not comfortable with using transfinite induction on ordinals...

Comment: Informal idea: Let $X=B\cap A$ for some $B\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$. Then $B$ can be constructed from open sets of $\Bbb R$ through countable unions and complements, with a possibly infinite sequence of operations. Both unions and complements commute with the intersection with $A$, so this gives you a way of building $X$ from open sets of $A$. Formal version of this idea: induction on the levels of the Borel hierarchy

Comment: Your question had no posted answer. So I posted a very simple and detailed proof that $$\{ B \cap A : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\} \subseteq 
\mathcal{B}(A)$$ I hope it will be clear for you. Please, let me know if you have any questions regarding my answer.

Comment: There is no need for transfinite induction on ordinals  nor Borel  hierarchies nor direct and inverse image maps with closure system. The solution is much simpler.

Comment: @Ramiro For complicated transfinite inductions along the Borel hierarchy there clearly is no need, however whether there is a need for direct and inverse image maps intimately depends on how profound an understanding one wants to gain of the overall phenomenon and up to what generality. This is not a matter of comparing "whose solution is simpler" -- and you seem to be intimating it is yours... -- when actually your second proof variant uses **precisely** the direct image construction that is explicitly described in my answer however is not done too much justice in yours, *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @Ramiro *(cont.)* in the sense that it is only cursorily mentioned without taking the time to expound on the very natural and more general phenomenon in the background. And if the option to give a "two-three liner" local answer -- referring strictly to the original problem and not going too far deeper beyond that -- does of course belong to the answer's author -- and I have no recommendations to make in that sense -- comments qualifying the simplicity of solution $A$ over solution $B$ -- when in fact solution $A$ tacitly relies on a machinery situated on a more profound level, *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @Ramiro *(cont.)* level which however it does not even care to explore, being just content with "finishing the job fast and easy" -- well, perhaps such comments are not entirely appropriate and even superfluous...Also, to be noted that closure systems are *absolutely indispensible* to any argument involving Borel $\sigma$-algebras, since by their very definition they are *generated* by an underlying topology and in order to implement this construction one inexorably must work with closure systems (at least by realising that the collection of all $\sigma$-algebras is one such system).

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Transfinite induction, Borel hierarchy and direct and inverse image maps with closure system are all relevant topics and the interest in studying them "depends on how profound an understanding one wants to gain of the overall phenomenon and up to what generality". 

**However**, none of them are necessary to answer the question as it is formulate. 

I presented a **simple** solution as it would appear in most first course on Measure Theory.  My second proof is just a slightly simpler variant of first proof. Both of my proofs does not depend on any additional "machinery".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116794/discussion-between--and-ramiro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already proved that
$\mathcal{B}(A) \subseteq  \{ B \cap A : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\} $, and your prooof is correct: $\{ B \cap A : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$ is a sigma algebra, which contains all the open sets of $A$. So $\mathcal{B}(A) \subseteq  \{ B \cap A : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\} $.

Let us prove, in a simple way, that
$$\{ B \cap A : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\} \subseteq 
\mathcal{B}(A)$$

**Proof**: Let $\tau$ be the collections of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $$K = \{ E \cup F : E  \in \mathcal{B}(A) \textrm{ and } F \in \mathcal{B}(A^c) \}$$

(note that $E$ and $F$ are disjoint). It is easy to see that $K$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. For all $O \in \tau$, $O =(O\cap A) \cup (O\cap A^c)$, $(O\cap A)\in\mathcal{B}(A)$ and  $(O\cap A^c)\in\mathcal{B}(A^c)$. So $O \in K$.  It follows that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq K$. So we have

$$\{ B \cap A : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\} \subseteq \{ G \cap A : G \in K\}$$

But $\{ G \cap A : G \in K\}=\mathcal{B}(A)$. So we have:
$$\{ B \cap A : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\} \subseteq 
\mathcal{B}(A)$$

**Remark**: A second way to do this proof (which is just a variant) is:

**Proof 2**: Let $\tau$ be the collections of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $$K = \{ G \subseteq \mathbb{R} :  G\cap A  \in \mathcal{B}(A)  \}$$

It is easy to see that $K$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. For all $O \in \tau$, $(O\cap A)\in\mathcal{B}(A)$. So $O \in K$. It follows that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq K$.

$$\{ B \cap A : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\} \subseteq \{ G \cap A : G \in K\}$$

But $\{G \cap A : G \in K\} \subseteq \mathcal{B}(A)$. So we have:
$$\{ B \cap A : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\} \subseteq 
\mathcal{B}(A)$$

Comment: Wow. How in the world did you come up with this proof?

Comment: @Albert Thanks. Both proofs are nice short proofs. They are the proofs we present when teaching a first  course on Measure Theory. The two proofs are just variant versions of each other.  They are examples of a standard basic technique, which consists in building an "auxiliary" $\sigma$- algebra to help us prove the result we want. The exact  "auxiliary" $\sigma$- algebra is usually not unique and it depends, of course, of what we are trying to prove.

Comment: @Albert One important aspect of good mathematics proofs is to use only what is necessary to prove the result. There are correct answers to your question using transfinite induction , using Borel hierarchies and so on. Those more complex "machinery" may be nice by themselves (and worth to learn), but **none** of them are really necessary to prove the result in your question.  Making a proof more complex than it needs to be is not a "virtue".

Comment: Thank you for your answers and perspectives! I always learn a lot from people who are much more experienced and knowledgeable in mathematics than I am. I hope to be as good as you some day : )

Answer (score 1):

This question permits a very elegant and general solution, which I would like to try and present. We begin by introducing a very elementary and equally important construction. For arbitrary map $f \colon A \to B$ and subsets $X \subseteq A$ respectively $Y \subseteq B$ we denote by $f[X]$ respectively $f^{-1}[Y]$ the direct respectively inverse images through $f$ of the subsets in question. We proceed to introduce **the direct and inverse image maps** as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\hat{f} \colon \mathscr{P}(A) &\to \mathscr{P}(B)\\
\hat{f}(X)&=f[X]\\
\check{f} \colon \mathscr{P}(B) &\to \mathscr{P}(A)\\
\check{f}(Y)&=f^{-1}[Y].
\end{align}$$
We also introduce another highly important notion: given fixed set $A$, we say $\mathscr{K}$ is a **closure system** on $A$ if $A \in \mathscr{K} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(A)$ such that for every nonempty $\varnothing \neq \mathscr{M} \subseteq \mathscr{K}$ we have that $\bigcap \mathscr{M} \in \mathscr{K}$. In natural language, $\mathscr{K}$ is a collection of subsets of $A$ containing $A$ in particular and closed with respect to *arbitrary* intersections. Given arbitrary subset $X \subseteq A$ we introduce the notation:
$$[X]_{\mathscr{K}}\colon=\bigcap_{\substack{M \in \mathscr{K}\\M \supseteq X}}M$$
for the *$\mathscr{K}$-substructure generated by* $X$, which is easily seen to be the minimum (with respect to inclusion) of the subset $\{M \in \mathscr{K} \mid M \supseteq X\}$.

We proceed to adopt the formal (and usual) definition according to which $\mathscr{M}$ is a **$\sigma$-algebra** on $A$ if $\varnothing \neq \mathscr{M} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(A)$ satisfies the axioms:
$$\begin{align}
&\left(\forall X \right)\left(X \in \mathscr{M}^{\mathbb{N}} \Rightarrow \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n \in \mathscr{M}\right)\\
&(\forall X)(X \in \mathscr{M} \Rightarrow A \setminus X \in \mathscr{M}).
\end{align}$$
For fixed set $A$ we denote by $\mathscr{Alg}^{\sigma}(A)$ the **collection of all $\sigma$-algebras** on $A$ and remark that it is a closure system on the powerset $\mathscr{P}(A)$.

Given an arbitrary map $f \colon A \to B$ we signal the following two important constructions:

1. Given a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{M} \in \mathscr{Alg}^{\sigma}(A)$ it holds that $\mathscr{N}\colon=\check{f}^{-1}\left[\mathscr{M}\right] \in \mathscr{Alg}^{\sigma}(B)$. We call this $\sigma$-algebra on $B$ the **direct image of $\mathscr{M}$ through $f$** and denote it by $f^{*}\left[\mathscr{M}\right]$. We also remark that it is by definition constituted of those $Y \subseteq B$ such that $f^{-1}[Y] \in \mathscr{M}$.
2. Given a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{N} \in \mathscr{Alg}^{\sigma}(B)$ it holds that $\mathscr{M}\colon=\check{f}\left[\mathscr{N}\right] \in \mathscr{Alg}^{\sigma}(A)$. We call this $\sigma$-algebra on $A$ the **inverse image of $\mathscr{N}$ through $f$** and denote it by $f_{*}\left[\mathscr{N}\right]$.

We make the important observation that given any two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathscr{M} \in \mathscr{Alg}^{\sigma}(A)$ and $\mathscr{N} \in \mathscr{Alg}^{\sigma}(B)$ we have the following **dualisation relation:** $f^{*}\left[\mathscr{M}\right] \supseteq \mathscr{N} \Leftrightarrow \mathscr{M} \supseteq f_{*}\left[\mathscr{N}\right]$.

Let us also note that in the particular case when $B \in \mathscr{M} \in \mathscr{Alg}^{\sigma}(A)$, if we denote by $\mathrm{i}^B_A \colon B \to A$ the respective inclusion map we have the following simple description: $\left(\mathrm{i}^B_A\right)_{*}\left[\mathscr{M}\right]=\{X \in \mathscr{M} \mid X \subseteq B\}$.

With these preparations in place, we can now state a very general:

> **Proposition.** Let $f \colon A \to B$ be an arbitrary map and $\mathscr{Y} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(B)$ be an arbitrary collection of subsets of $B$. Then the relation $f_{*}\left[\left[\mathscr{Y}\right]_{\mathscr{Alg}^{\sigma}(B)}\right]=\left[\check{f}\left[\mathscr{Y}\right]\right]_{\mathscr{Alg}^{\sigma}(A)}$ holds.

*Proof.* For ease of notation let us write $\mathscr{X}\colon=\check{f}\left[\mathscr{Y}\right] \subseteq \mathscr{P}(A)$, $\mathscr{N}\colon=\left[\mathscr{Y}\right]_{\mathscr{Alg}^{\sigma}(B)}$, $\mathscr{M}\colon=\left[\mathscr{X}\right]_{\mathscr{Alg}^{\sigma}(A)}$ respectively $\mathscr{M'}\colon=f_{*}\left[\mathscr{N}\right]$. Our objective thus becomes to show that $\mathscr{M}=\mathscr{M'}$.

On the one hand we have by definition that $\mathscr{Y} \subseteq \mathscr{N}$ whence $\mathscr{X}=\check{f}\left[\mathscr{Y}\right] \subseteq \check{f}\left[\mathscr{N}\right]=\mathscr{M'}$. Since $\mathscr{M'}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $A$ including $\mathscr{X}$ we infer that $\mathscr{M} \subseteq \mathscr{M'}$.

On the other hand, since  by construction $\mathscr{M} \supseteq \mathscr{X}=\check{f}\left[\mathscr{Y}\right]$ we have $f^{*}\left[\mathscr{M}\right]=\check{f}^{-1}\left[\mathscr{M}\right] \supseteq \check{f}^{-1}\left[\check{f}\left[\mathscr{Y}\right]\right] \supseteq \mathscr{Y}$. Since $f^{*}\left[\mathscr{M}\right]$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $B$ including $\mathscr{Y}$ we infer that $f^{*}\left[\mathscr{M}\right] \supseteq \mathscr{N}$ which by virtue of the dualisation relation mentioned above leads to $\mathscr{M} \supseteq \mathscr{M'}$, thus bringing our argument to an end. $\Box$

Given a fixed topology $\mathscr{T}$ on a set $X$ let us abbreviate by $\mathscr{B}\left(\mathscr{T}\right)\colon=\left[\mathscr{T}\right]_{\mathscr{Alg}^{\sigma}(X)}$ the *Borel* $\sigma$-algebra associated to the space $(X, \mathscr{T})$. If we adopt notations similar to the ones above for *initial* and *final* topologies induced by arbitrary maps, the general proposition above applies in the following particular form to Borel $\sigma$-algebras:

> **Corollary.**  Let $(Y, \mathscr{T})$ be an arbitrary space and $f \colon X \to Y$ an arbitrary map. We then have the relation $f_{*}\left[\mathscr{B}\left(\mathscr{T}\right)\right]=\mathscr{B}\left(f_{*}\left[\mathscr{T}\right]\right)$.

The result you are interested in is a special case of the above corollary, when the map $f$ is an inclusion map.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is very enlightening.

Comment: @Albert Glad you found it so! If you permit me to give here an answer to a question you addressed to Ramiro in the comment section appended to his answer, the reason he came up with the proof he gave -- which is quite standard -- and those particular auxiliary $\sigma$-algebras is because they occur as particular instances of the construction of direct/inverse image of $\sigma$-algebras that I wanted to introduce in full generality in the answer above. These constructions are implicit when considering Borel $\sigma$-algebras induced on subspaces etc and they "make the game" so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

The family $\mathcal S=\{X\subseteq\mathbb R:X\cap A\in\mathcal B(A)\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\mathbb R$, and it contains all open subsets of $\mathbb R$ (because their intersections with $A$ are open in the subspace topology of $A$). So $\mathcal S$ contains all of the Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$.